# Ionic2 array access in template

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-template

I'm trying to show data in my template coming from a `json` in the controller.

All the alternatives I found refers to using `ngFor`, but I don't want to iterate all the items, because I want to show just one of them.

```
getServicio(servicioId: number) {
        let getServicio = 'services?id=' + servicioId;
        this.http.getRequest(getServicio) //returns a json
            .then(
            res => {
                this.services = res[0];
            }
            )
            .catch(
            error => console.log(error)
            );
    }
```

And in the template I simply write:

```
{{services.id}}
```

It gives me an error:

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Isn't there any alternative to do it? Or in another way, passing all the data to the template and getting into the array with an index like:

```
{{services[0].id}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: services is undefined while the HTTP response hasn't been received yet. Use ngIf to avoid displaying it while it's undefined, or use `services?.id`. BTW, why do you name it `services` if it's supposed to be a single service. And why does getRequest return an array, since you're passing the ID of the unique object to retrieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to display data (`services.id`) before it arrives (http requests are asynchronous) - which means `services.id` is `undefined` at the time the template is rendered. Simplest solution is to use **safe navigation operator** (`?`) to "protect" your template until data arrive:

```
{{services?.id}}
```

You can also use `ngIf` directive so the part of the template where you want to display `services` is not rendered until `services` is defined:

```
<div *ngIf="services">
    {{services?.id}}
</div>
```

Read more about safe navigation operator (`?`) [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator) and more about `ngIf` directive [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html).